# Kernel Addition and one Surprisingly facts?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, pattern-recognition, feature-selection, kernel-density

if k1 and k2 be a kernel in space R^n*R^n we know `k(x,z)=ak1(x,z) + bk2(x,z)` (kernel addition) is still a kernel (valid kernel) if `a,b >= 0` (a,b is real numbers, scalar) . That this is valid can be seen from the fact that the results of the kernel function can be interpreted as inner products in feature space. Adding the inner products together amounts to adding both feature spaces together. but today i'm so surprised when I read my notes. my TA says  `k(x,z)=ak1(x,z) + bk2(x,z) (kernel addition)` is still a kernel if `a<0,b>0` or `a>0,b<0` !!!

> is it possible to still there is a valid kernel with `a<0,b>0` and `a>0,b<0`? any expert could
>   help me ?

Comment: This question probably has more sense in a different site, try http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think it's more practical and good for SO. @KeillRandor thanks for your hint. I well in stats.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that `a * M1 + b * M2`, with `M1`,`M2` positive definite matrices and `a<0,b>0` is also a positive definite matrix? Which it isn't. I think your TA is wrong, or some qualification is missing.

Comment: It is not hard to construct a trivial example to show that it is incorrect, both `a, b` need to be non negative.

Comment: Wait, do you mean that `k` would be valid for *any* `k1,k2,a>0,b<0`? I don't think that's true. Or do you mean are there *some* `k1,k2,a>0,b<0` for which `k` is valid? That's easy, just take `k1=k2,a=1,b=-0.5` and you get a valid kernel...

Comment: @nikie for a>0,b<0  K(x,z)=aK1(x,z)+bK2(x,z) is valid kernel function. and for a<0,b>0  K(x,z)=aK1(x,z)+bK2(x,z) is valid kernel function

Comment: If you mean "there are some a,b,k1,k2 that will give a valid kernel `a*k2+b*k2`", then you're right. If you mean "for *any* a,b,k1,k2 `a*k2+b*k2` is a valid kernel", then you're wrong. I don't know which one it is.

Comment: would you please submit as an answer to learn me? consider two case?  @nikie

Comment: 1K1-0/5 K2  is valid kernel ?!!!!!! @nikie

Answer (score 1):

A [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel) should be non-negative for all equal inputs. Let's denote an arbitrary kernel (RBF, for example) as `K`.

Let's consider `K1` = `K2` = `K`.

Define `K3 = a K1 + b K2`. Let `a = -2`, `b = 1`. Then `K3(x, x) = -K(x, x)`, which fails to satisfy kernel's definition.

Now, the example above show that statement of your TA is not true in general, for any `K1`, `K2`, `a` and `b`. There are, obviously, some combinations of these that will result in a proper kernel.

I suppose, the necessary condition for it would be something like `λmin(a K1) + λmin(b K2) >= 0` where `λmin` means the smallest [eigenvalue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) of an operator. `λmin(c K)` is equal to `c λmin(K)` for non-negative `c`, and `c λmax(K)` for a negative one. Consider `a=2`, `b=-1` with the same kernels as above as an example.

In case of both `a < 0` and `b < 0`, though, no valid kernel can be forged. This is easy to see: if `K3(x, x) > 0`, then, `K3(x, x) = a K1(x, x) + b K2(x, x) = -|a| K1(x, x) - |b| K2(x, x) > 0` since `a` and `b` are negative. This leads to `|a| K1(x, x) + |b| K2(x, x) < 0` which can't be true since `K1` and `K2` are valid kernels.

Comment: would you please add an example that under these two conditions the K3 be a valid kernel ?

Comment: @AnjelaDark, sure! Take a=2, b=-1 in my example above :-) (NB: there was an typo in my answer, now it's fixed)

Comment: my second question is can we make a combination that for a<0, b<0 that has a valid kernel ?

Comment: please add your answer to my comment in whole in your answer, thanks .

Comment: @AnjelaDark, done. Also, I fixed another mistake: kernel doesn't have to be non-negative on all inputs, just on equal ones.

Comment: would you please consider a case a<0, b>0 ?

Comment: K=aK1(x,z)+bk2(x,z) for a<0,b<0 and k1=k2 not valid kernel. K=aK1(x,z)+bk2(x,z) for a=2, b=-1 and k1=k2 is valid kernel. what about a<0, b>0 that be valid kernel?  My conclusion is right?

Comment: @AnjelaDark there's no difference between the case `a < 0, b > 0` and the `a > 0, b < 0`, they're symmetrical.